# Wrong 1st Argument Found in Smooch Implementation

Tags: android

I'm developing this App using Smooch, it gives the error as wrong Argument found in 1st parameter.

[image: Error message]

How can I fix it?

```
package com.abc.support;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Bundle;

import io.smooch.core.Settings;
import io.smooch.core.Smooch;
import io.smooch.core.SmoochCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Smooch.init(MainActivity.this, new Settings("fdsfdsfd"), new SmoochCallback() {
            @Override
            public void run(Response response) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the guidelines about how to ask a good question here on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A small hint for your problem: In the error message stated what the method got and what it expected (Found / Required).

Comment: so, what do I write there, please a hint ?

Comment: Post your full code I can't help you if I can't see your code. So read the guidelines, correct your question and then I can help you!

Comment: @thmspl added please see

Answer (score 0):

The [javadocs](https://docs.smooch.io/api/android/) state, that the first argument is an instance of `Application` and not an instance of `Context`. Therefore, simply put the code into an `Application` class, instead of an `Activity` class, so that `this` will reference the expected argument.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message the first argument need's to be of the type `android.app.Application`. So the fastest way to reach this would be to call the `Smooch.init(..` method in your application class instead of your activity class.

Your application class extends from `android.app.Application` and so `this` will have the correct type if you use it as an argument.